# Убрать перенос строки в начале текста

Tags: php, wordpress

Текст берется из базы данных и при выводе на экран, вставляет новый абзац.

Все бы ничего, но задача сделать так, что бы брался первый абзац текста и шел в описание. И тут как раз тут начинаются проблемы...

Все работает до момента, пока в одном из текстов не встречается символ &nbsp и тут, вместо ожидаемого текста втыкается &nbsp и хвост:"Читать далее"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Trim не помогает, регулярки тоже ожидаемого результата не приносили.

Должно быть вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код обработки контента:

```
$text    = "";
$content = preg_replace( '~\[[^\]]+\]~', '', get_the_content() );
$content = strip_tags( $content );
$content = trim( $content, "\r/\n" );
$content = explode( "\r\n", $content );
$content = preg_split( '//u', $content[0] );
$length  = count( $content );
for ( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++ ) {
    if ( $i > 1000 && $content[ $i ] == " " ) {
        $length = $i;
        break;
    }
}
for ( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++ ) {
    $text .= $content[ $i ];
}
$text = trim( $text ) . "\nЧитать далее...";
```

Comment: Как правильно задать вопрос по WordPress?
 https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress

Comment: Опубликуйте код, как Вы обрабатываете текст из базы и выводите его

Comment: @Евгений `&nbsp;` это пробел, а не перенос.